# Проблема с возвращением текста richTextBox

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день, не могу понять почему richTextBox не возвращает текст

> вот так работает

```
private void richTextBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = richTextBox3.Text;
}
```

> а так нет

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox3.Text, new Font("Arial", 11), Brushes.Black, 10, 25);
    }
```

все находиться в пределах одного класса.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что проблема точно не в DrawString? Т.е. richTextBox3.Text возвращает null?

Comment: в любой части метода printDocument1_PrintPage richTextBox3.Text всегда равен пусто, DrawString здесь не причем

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть, что у Вас получается на выходе. "Не работает" – довольно растяжимое понятие.

Comment: @SergD29 проверьте, в какой момент вы вызываете метод `Print()`. Может быть текст еще не загружен в `RichTextBox`?

Comment: текст загружается сразу с запуском программы, хотя это тоже не имеет значение, пробовал писать и печатать все равно пусто, спасают глобальные переменные

Comment: Код у Вас абсолютно рабочий, скорее всего как сказал @SergD29 текст еще не загрузился, а Вы вызвали метод печати. Попробуйте временную задержку Thread.Sleep(1000) перед Print() поставить.